# Tooltip never closes when state change

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a breadcrumb:

`Home > Page 1 > Page 1.1`

On each parent page (`Home`, `Page 1`) I'd like to show a bootstrap tooltip containing details about this page. That works fine.

However, when I hit the tab key until I reach a button linking to another page and hit enter, the page change but the tooltip stays open and never closes, even if I get back to the page and click anywhere.

Here is the template:

```
<a ui-sref="home"
   title="Home"
   class="btn btn-default contains-tooltip">
       <span class="fa fa-home"></span>
</a>
<a ng-repeat="page in breadcrumb"
   ui-sref="{{ page.href }}"
   class="btn btn-default contains-tooltip"
   title="{{ page.description }}"
   ng-bind-html="page.title"></a>
```

And the related JS:

```
$('.contains-tooltip').tooltip({
  container: 'body',
  html: true,
  trigger: 'hover',
  placement 'bottom'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`$(...).tooltip` is not aware of state changes because it's outside Angular. You have to force the tooltips to hide.

Add an event listener that will hide all tooltips when the route is changed.

```
app.module('myApp').run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',function() {
        $('.contains-tooltip').tooltip('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: @YannBertrand To continue on the 'outside of Angular' aspect, do you know about the angular-ui-bootstrap module? It integrates bootstrap's components into angular and is supposed to take care of such aspects.

Comment: @Aaron actually that's a better answer. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia you can add it to your answer